# Transformation parameter as learning target

Tags: pytorch, dataset, torchvision

Let's say, I am applyng random blur to `torchvision` `MNIST` image, and want to train the net to guess blur power. It looks natural to use standard `transform`, but in dataset class implementation transformations of data and target applyes independently:

```
    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)
```

So I can't see a way to pass blur value for insertion in target.

Well, I can rewrite dataset class, but may be there is more natural way to pass parameter from data `transform` to `target_transform`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own approach, thow I looking for more elegant:

```
def myBlur( t):
    sigm = ( random.uniform(0.1,12.0) )
    t = torchvision.transforms.functional.gaussian_blur( t, 15, sigm )
    return ( t, sigm )

class MyMNIST( torchvision.datasets.MNIST ):
                                   
    @property
    def processed_folder(self) -> str:
        # we want files from 'MNIST' folder, not from __classname__ == 'MyMNIST'
        return os.path.join(self.root, 'MNIST', 'processed')

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
        img, target = self.data[index], int(self.targets[index])
        img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode='L')

        # call all transformations here explicitly
        img = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(img)
        img = torchvision.transforms.Resize( (96,96) )(img)
        img, dd = myBlur( img )
        img = torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))(img)

        return img, dd
```